# Is there an easy way to suppress footnotes and citations?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I'm looking to perform a word count on a long PDF that contains many footnotes and citations. Is there an easy way to prevent basically anything that would appear as a footnote, including auto-citations in BibLaTeX, from being printed?

MWE (compiles with XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=usmax]{english}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{lib.bib}
@book{foobar,
title = {Foo},
author = {John Bar},
location = {Footown},
publisher = {Bar},
date = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{lib.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text that I want to be in the word count.\autocite[Prenote][Postnote]{foobar} Some more text.\footnote{A footnote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{}` would be my first guess, but i haven't tested it.

Comment: So I thought of something similar. The difficulty is with \autocite, where there can be multiple optional arguments. I was hoping that there was something that would just suppress the printing of the box under the line where footnotes are printed.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example for the convenience of the helpers.

Comment: I wonder if you could abuse pdfcrop to remove the footnotes.  This would of course be difficult if there's no single value for the amount you'd need to crop from the bottom.  Alternatively, why are you counting words in the .pdf and not the source -- using texcount or possibly your editor if it's tex-aware (there are many good reasons for both ways).

Comment: Third idea.  What happens if you delete all your aux files and *just* run pdflatex once.  Does biblatex put placeholders in? Are they counted as words? Can they be counted uniquely and subtracted?

Comment: @ChrisH I can copy the separate chapters (which are separate tex files) into something to count the words. Because I'm using a chromebook, I only have access to ShareLaTeX. I could use TexCount online, but it doesn't have the option to exclude footnotes.

Comment: I'm afraid you're second answer presupposes an understanding of the compiling process that I'm lacking. With shareLaTeX, I think these files are hidden from me.

Comment: Working online only makes it harder but it looks like texcount allows you to add/overwrite command definitions via comments in your .tex file -- see p17 onwards in [the manual](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/DOC/TeXcount_3_0_0_24.pdf).  It has a --nobib option, but I've never used bibliographic footnotes so you may want to do your own testing

Comment: I guess I'll pursue that line then. Thanks!

Comment: Did you actually try `\renewcommand\footnote[1]{}`? Or do you simply guess that it doesn't work?

Comment: redefining `footnote` works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, yes it did work on my MWE! I had tried it on my actual project and it didn't work. It's a pretty massive document so hopefully be able to understand why it's not working there.

Comment: Comment out the lines where you add your bibliographic resources (`\addbibresources{file}`) and then you'll just get bold question marks instead of all your citations.

Comment: @AndrewCashner Thanks, this worked on my bigger document as well as my MWE. Ends up being one word per missing reference.

Comment: @Johannes_B Would you mind turning your comment into an answer. It worked for the MWE and is a good idea. With all we have to go on, it is also a correct solution to the question posed.

Comment: @moewe Your request was delayed because the kids wanted to play on a sunday. Just provided a short answer :-)

Comment: Did you try converting footnotes to endnotes and dumping the end of the document / not printing them? I usually do this whenever I want to perform such tasks.

Answer (score 2):

If you redefine the `footnote` command to do exactly nothing, no footnote will be printed in your document.

```
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{}
```